# Isogonal Conjugates

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]
[image]

[image]

When approaching this problem, i tried to use the trigonometric form of Ceva's theorem, and in fact, if you define the isogonal conjugate so that $P'A,P'C$ and $P'B$ are reflections of $PA,PC,PB$ respectively, then you can show that way that those lines are concurrent, for example this way:
[image]

But the thing is that when trying to solve it the other way around, when you have the concurrency and two of the angle relations, I tried reversing the previous proof, but if you apply Ceva to the triangle, and you use the two angle relations you have in those, you get,finally:
$$ \frac{\sin\angle ACP}{\sin\angle PCB} \times \frac{\sin\angle ACP'}{\sin\angle P'CB} = 1$$

which is not enough to justify $$\angle ACP = \angle P'CB$$

Can someone explain me how to use this to get to the final result? I understand that it's basically the same question using the three angle conditions and then proving they concur, but i was just wondering if this also is posible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since$$\angle ACP+\angle PCB=\angle ACP^\prime+\angle P^\prime CB=\angle ACB,$$we just need to use the fact that$$\frac{\sin(\theta-x)}{\sin x}=\sin\theta\cot x-\cos\theta$$decreases as $x$ increases from $0$ to $\theta:=\angle ACB$. Since your sine ratios are reciprocals of each other rather than equal, it follows that$$\angle ACP=\theta-\angle ACP^\prime=\angle P^\prime CB,$$as required.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the inbetween steps you used? I don't understand how decreasing nature of that expression was used or how the final equation only involving angles was arrived at.

Comment: @Typo Let $f(x):=\csc x\sin(\theta-x)$ so $f(\theta-x)=1/f(x)$ (the other crucial observation), so $\angle ACP=\angle P'CB$ because $f(\angle ACP)=1/f(\angle ACP')=f(P'CB)$.

Comment: Thank you, that's more illuminating and quite clever. Sorry to bother you again though, how can you guarantee f is injective so that the arguments can be equaled (since sin(x) = sin($\pi$-x) and whatnot)? Is that what requires that decreasing fact, and if so, how? My analysis concepts are weak... 
Relatedly, I noticed my try of this problem led to sine ratios equaling each other, thus your cotangent identity gives a similar situation again of g(ACP) = g(ACP') with g being cot.

Comment: @Typo Whereas my comment wrote $f$ as a ratio, my answer wrote it as a linear transformation of $\cot x$.